# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left (\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+2} \right )$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

What would you say about this series about convergence and absolute convergence?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left (\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+2} \right )$$

In use with: $$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: I'd say its cute.

Comment: Factor out $(-1)^n$ then find a common denominator.

Comment: @copper.hat Would you really say that? ;-)

Comment: @Dr.MV: Maybe amusing rather than cute :-).

Comment: @copper.hat Now that comment was "amusing."

Comment: My comment above was tongue-in-cheek, but note that with the terms $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+2}$, the series is absolutely convergent, but if you split it up into $\cdots, \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}, \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+2}, \cdots $, it is no longer absolutely convergent. So, the representation of a series is very relevant.

Comment: Yes, the representation is important.  Recall how one can extend the definition of $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$ for $\text{Re}(s)>1$ to $\zeta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$ for $\text{Re}(s)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$
then compare with $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: Please take care with those parentheses.